# Download MapBox offline map and store it on internal storage

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

Is it possible to download a MapBox map as a file on a computer rather than mobile. Then load that file into iOS and Android MapBox SDK?

The idea is to have many phones who will never have internet access and just to load the map off internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Talked to MapBox reps and it looks like this isn't possible without being on the MapBox Enterprise plan. There is not functionality in the public API for this to work.